# Can online ckbuilder be used to build a prior version of ckeditor?

Tags: ckeditor

My company has strict rules about which versions we can use of open source software like CKEditor.  Right now we are on 4.4.7.

I want to start using the online CKBuilder to bundle everything in a single ckeditor.js file.  But it seems like the online builder at http://ckeditor.com/builder only deals with the latest version.

Is there a way to run the online CKBuilder against a prior release of CKEditor?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can change the way the online CKBuilder works, but you can run it locally with whatever version you want: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_build